# Breaking out Vaadin widgetset compilation

Tags: maven, maven-3, vaadin, vaadin7

In order to save time compiling, I'm trying to break out the compilation of the widgetsets to a TeamCity build project of its own, we're using nexus as repo. The Vaadin "base project" is then to contain a dependency to the widgetset artifact to fetch the current version. I'm sure this has been done before.

The widgetset project builds fine in TeamCity. The jars and poms are correctly uploaded to nexus. I have unpacked the jars to make sure everything was in its place. So far so good.

In eclipse, the base project does fetch the widgetset artifact and contain it in its library. Seems good.

However, when I do a "mvn clean package" on the base project from eclipse and run it on Tomcat, I get the following error in the web browser:

```
Failed to load the widgetset: ./VAADIN/widgetsets/com.example.somerandomapp.web.AppWidgetSet/com.example.somerandomapp.web.AppWidgetSet.nocache.js?1376642850734
```

When I check the project structure, I find no VAADIN/widgetset-folder under the target folder. Additionally, in the maven dependency jar-file, there are one VAADIN folder containing gwt-unitCache and one VAADIN.widgetsets-folder containing the widgetset-goodies, as well as the - in the error message above - mentioned file.

I cannot get my head around this. I'm no maven pro, so I may have missed something trivial there. Also I'm no Vaadin pro, so I might as well have missed something just as trivial there.

I really hope there is someone out there that could help me get this ship in the water. I would greatly appreciate it!

Vaadin version: 7.1.1
Maven version: 3.0.4

My base project's pom.xml (leaving out some stuff for brevity):

```xml
<dependencies>

    <!-- Some Random App - Commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.somerandomapp.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>somerandomapp-common-widgetset</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Vaadin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax-servlet-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My widgetset-pom (leaving out some stuff for brevity):

```xml
<!-- same Vaadin-plugins as in the "base project" -->
<!-- maven compiler, release, javadoc, deploy and source artifacts -->
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-clean-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <filesets>
                <fileset>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</directory>
                </fileset>
            </filesets>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
            <!-- <runTarget>mobilemail</runTarget> -->
            <!-- We are doing "inplace" but into subdir VAADIN/widgetsets. This 
                 way compatible with Vaadin eclipse plugin. -->
            <webappDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
            <hostedWebapp>${project.build.outputDirectory}/VAADIN/widgetsets</hostedWebapp>
            <noServer>true</noServer>
            <!-- Remove draftCompile when project is ready -->
            <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
            <compileReport>true</compileReport>
            <style>OBF</style>
            <strict>true</strict>
            <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/</runTarget>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                   <goal>clean</goal>
                    <goal>resources</goal>
                    <goal>update-theme</goal>
                    <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                    <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>    
        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
            only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[7.1.1,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>update-theme</goal>
                                    <goal>resources</goal>
                                    <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                                    <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore />
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
```

**Update:**
I have setup my MainUI class like this:

```xml
@WebServlet(value = {"/foo/*", "/VAADIN/*"} , asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MainUI.class, widgetset = "com.example.somerandomapp.common.widgetset.AppWidgetSet")
```

I realised this has something to do with it and changed it to the correct widgetset. But I still get the same error:

```xml
Failed to load the widgetset: ./VAADIN/widgetsets/com.example.somerandomapp.common.widgetset.AppWidgetSet/com.example.somerandomapp.common.widgetset.AppWidgetSet.nocache.js?1376662202437
```

Now, this error shows the correct path to the nocache-file in the classpath, which makes me very confused, because the file is there, in the lib folder.
I hope this didn't confuse you further....

**Update 2:**
Actually this is adequate:

```xml
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MainUI.class, widgetset = "com.example.somerandomapp.common.widgetset.AppWidgetSet")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change you see after the update of my OP was what was missing.

I'm not sure why Vaadin didn't find the resources at first, but after I wiped the "base project" from disk and re-fetched it from SVN, did a project clean and a maven update on it, as well as a Tomcat working directory clean, it magically worked. I guess there was some cached content laying around. I hope this can be to help for anyone else who wants to break out the Vaadin widgetsets to a project of its own!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Vaadin wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using%20Vaadin%20with%20Maven) (You can find pom.xml example here)

> If your project uses custom GWT widgets, you will need to compile them
>   with the GWT compiler. This can be done using the Codehaus GWT Maven
>   Plugin.

You have to compile widgetset with [GWT maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/) (It's a little bit tricky with this plugin cuz you have to download GWT SDK i think)

> If the 'vaadin-maven-plugin' is used, the widgetset (if any) can be
>   automatically updated based on project dependencies. This is achieved
>   with the Maven goal 'vaadin:update-widgetset' followed by
>   'gwt:compile'. Running the goal clean (or gwt:clean) prior to
>   vaadin:update-widgetset is recommended.

Comment: I am not entirely sure this is needed using Vaadin 7.1.1. All examples I have seen is using the vaadin-maven-plugin. The examples you linked are all from Vaadin 6, back when GWT was not a core component of Vaadin.

Again, everything compiles just fine. The problem resides in that Vaadin cannot locate the widgetset in the library.

Comment: Well, i think there is no big difference between 6 and 7 from GWT perspective. Widgetsets are used the same way. If you want to use your own widgetset you need to compile it with GWT, there is no other way i suppose.

Comment: My goal here is not to use "my own" widgetset. I'm not even using any widgets/addons/plugins right now. In fact, the widgetset and the build process of it is the very same as when first I created the project. What I'm looking for is to break the widgetset out of my main project to a project of its own, so that I can run the widgetset in a separate build process. To Vaadin, in this case, it is the same widgetset no matter where you compile it, isn't it? Maybe I am misinterpreting what you are trying to tell me. In that case I do apologize!

Comment: Roger, the name of Default Vaadin widgeset is `com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet`. So, I you want to use widgetset with the name `com.example.somerandomapp.common.widgetset.AppWidgetSet` it is "your own" widgetset in despite of it inherits just and only from default vaadin widgetset. *So, anyway you have to compile it with GWT*. Or i don't know if it would work, but you can copy default widgeset from vaadin-client-compiled to webapps/VAADIN and rename it to your namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, Milan! If you read the update that I made two days ago, in the OP, you can see that the widgetset-name was  one of the things I was missing. The reason that it didn't work must have been some cached content (read my answer). I'm still not using GWT per-se, I think that the "vaadin-maven-plugin" takes care of that automatically (i.e. "built-in") in V7 (correct me if I'm wrong).